# not able to import module in Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1?

Tags: android, android-studio

while trying to import module from `File -> New -> Import-Module` options it's open `Import Module from Source` dialog but after selecting the path of the module finish button not enabling it remains disabled.

I don't know why the finish button is not enabling even if choose the correct source directory of the module and this started to happen after I updated android studio to arctic fox.

in the older version of the android studio, it's working fine.

please help me

[image]

Comment: That is a bug in AS . You need to do all the stuffs manually

Comment: check in settings.gradle file is this module already added before. Like this:  include ':app' ,':imagepicker'

Comment: @DeePanShu module not added in settings.gradle

Comment: then you have to add manually

Comment: i installed previous version of android studio and it's working fine

Comment: this problem only happen in android studio arctic fox

Answer (score 0):

This Bug is in Android studio Arctic Fox. Try to add it manually in this sequence:

1. copy `your-module` folder in your project directory
2. Add below line in `settings.gradle`

```js
include ':your-module' // your-module is module name
```

3. click `sync now`
4. Done